# Mom too worried with germs and disease

Tags: hygiene, cleaning, anxiety

I've a six month old baby. He's very healthy. My girlfriend (his mom)
is literally terrified by the "dirt, germs, bacteria, and viruses" and any
illness they could cause.

So..just to name a few, she wash child hands constantly when other adults touch them. She wash floors and baby toys after someone came into the house. And she does not allow that other babies (ie. his cousins) touch our baby...

I think that all this is a bit too exaggerated, especially the isolation from other babies - although I understand the concern. My girlfriend say that she behaves so until our baby will be one year old.

She is right, or she is following her fears?

Comment: I suggest that you do some research about the [hygiene hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygiene_hypothesis) and stop desinfecting all and sundry.

Comment: Just as a general rule, it's best not to tell someone who is suffering from unhealthy anxiety that they shouldn't worry about it. If your baby is immunocompromised, or has other special concerns, those precautions may be necessary. You two should talk to the baby's doctor about it at the next well-baby visit if one is coming up soon. Doctors are there to answer these kinds of questions for new parents.

Comment: A [couple months of general isolation](http://www.babble.com/baby/taking-newborn-baby-outside-health/) to mom and dad are usually good; a year is too much. Once baby's skin is populated with his/her own personal colony of familiar "bugs", that's probably the best first-line of defense. A couple months allows the colonization by most things that are in the common environment and generates the immune reactions to them. And then, scrubbing that layer off becomes a questionable act. Simple soapy rinsing is enough.

Comment: While a tad excessive, I don't think this is so far beyond "normal". Most new parents go to great lengths to protect their first child, attempting to take every conceivable precaution. Your second child, however... they'll eat off the floor right in front of you, and you'll just shrug it off. ;)

Comment: @LindseyD - my wife and I called it the "Binky Cleanliness Factor". With a first child, if the binky (pacifier) slips out of their mouth (even if it only touches their clothes) it gets scrubbed, bleached, and UV-sterilized before being returned to the baby. With the second child, if the binky falls to the floor the parent rinses it off under running water then returns it to the baby. Third kid: binky lands in a pile of dirt, parent wipes the obvious crud off on their pant-leg and shoves it back in the kid's face. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis Haha, spot on! I attribute this to a couple of things... (1) "Hey my first kid's still alive, so clearly they're not _that_ fragile", and (2) You start to realize that there are _real_ challenges to deal with, so you stop creating extra work for yourself.

Comment: @BobJarvis, I call it the Quarter Rule.  First kid swallows a quarter, you rush them to the emergency room, by the fourth kid you're like "that's coming out of your allowance, kid"

Comment: Where do you live? If you lived in a big city like Hong Kong, with a history of SARS and other epidemics you may very well learn to behave like your wife. Don't judge too soon ;-)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Babies/children build up their immune systems by being exposed to germs and dirt. Keeping them away from germs and dirt actually gives them a weaker immune system. (http://www.webmd.com/parenting/d2n-stopping-germs-12/kids-and-dirt-germs)

This is not to say that you should bring your baby hang out with plague victims. Some germs (mold etc) can make baby really sick.

The following web page gives some sensible guidelines: http://www.whattoexpect.com/first-year/germs-and-babies.aspx

Comment: But if it survives hanging out with plague victims, it'll be one badass baby.

Comment: My kids went to school with a couple of children who were allergic to just about everything. Their mom was a hyper-clean freak. Might just be coincidence. Our kids grew up on a farm, with the concomitant dirt, dust, pollen, and you-don't-really-want-to-know all over the place. We've got one daughter who's allergic to gluten (inherited from my wife), but other than that they're fine - they don't even get hay fever.

Comment: I've a friend who experienced this from her mother growing up. Utter sterility, even immune system boosting drugs(!!). Said friend rarely got sick for the first few years of her life. The doctors, however, concluded that unless things changed *right away* she was going to die if anything significant hit, because her immune system was natively so weak and dependent on sterility and external boosters. She still has a poor immune system to this day, and doesn't even like handling coins. Meanwhile I handle dirty stuff all the time and I'm about as fine as she is.

Comment: @BobJarvis There's probably some scientific background to that, may be the start of the ultimate answer to this question.

Comment: Typical @Voldemort - just pure evil.

Comment: @Voldemort I really don't have anything to do with parenting, but I joined this community only to up vote your comment :D

Comment: I agree. I was raised in a house of absolute uncleanliness. I was exposed to everything. I slept with roaches and black widows and almost positively every creepy crawly that could exist within a swamp cooled house. I was a very happy kid and I am now a fully grown adult with an immune system that would laugh at aids. I never get sick and our kids have an amazing immune system as well. I'd be more concerned with the exposure to chemicals than germs. if it kills 99% of bacteria, what's it doing to you?

Comment: @BobJarvis: May not be a coincidence, current immunological research suggests a "hygiene hypothesis" which says that too sterile an environment early in life can lead to an over-reactive immune system. There is no smoking gun, though, and plenty of counter-examples and contemporaneous changes that are hard to factor out of large cohort studies. (I'm a good example of a counter-example: I have a bunch of allergies, and when I was young my parents were anything but neat freaks.) We know too *little* hygiene is also bad, we may have just gone too far the other way.

Comment: The trouble with those links is they don't lay any really evidence- even anecdotal. You can find lots of that in books but it wouldn't convince anyone who doesn't accept it anyway.

Answer (score 22):

(Disclaimer: I am not a doctor, your doctor or your girlfriend's doctor)

It is possible that your girlfriend is experiencing postpartum obsessive-compulsive disorder (OCD). The hormonal changes during and after pregnancy are associated with multiple mental health issues, most prominent postpartum depression, but also the lesser known postpartum anxiety and postpartum OCD.

While the most common symptom of postpartum OCD are obsessive thoughts about harming the infant, another symptom is fear of exposing the child to something harmful, for example diseases or toxins.

If you talk to your girlfriend and get the impression that she is having intrusive thoughts, or can't stop doing what she is doing, or get the impression that she herself is suffering from her actions, try to suggest talking to her doctor (whichever doctor she trusts most - for example her gynecologist, pediatrician or GP can all refer her to a specialist) about it. While the OCD often goes away on its own, the symptoms can be treated.

Again, not saying that this is definitely the case here, but it is something to be aware of. Talking to her about why she does what she is doing (is she afraid the child will die, for example?) showing her that this is not  recommended should be the first thing to do.

Estimates of how many women show postpartum OCD vary greatly - I could find estimates between 1 and 10 percent. Unfortunately, most scientific studies I could find about this are behind a pay wall.

[Prenatal and Postnatal OCD](http://www.ocduk.org/prenatal-postnatal-ocd)

[Onset and Exacerbation of Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder in Pregnancy and the Postpartum Period](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4204467/)

Comment: Talking to her about why she does this has already taken place (germs). OCD is a disorder for mental health professionals. The gynecologist is out of the picture by now. A pediatrician can make a referral, however,

Comment: @anongoodnurse right, I meant pediatrician. Didn't think this would be read as "that doctor could treat her", more as a "talk to the doctor you are already seeing, who can refer her". But yeah, didn't really write that, edited to make that clear.

Answer (score 4):

On top of Dave Clarke's answer (which is **the** answer in my opinion), I would suggest that you and your girlfriend look at other people's kids of different ages and talk to their parents. My wife and I could tell you stories of all the disgusting things our kids licked and chewed, and they survived fine to be (so far!) well-adjusted teenagers.

Answer (score 4):

Like Martin, I think Dave's answer is *the* correct one --too sterile an environment has been convincingly shown to be harmful.  However, I think it's also important to understand this from your girlfriend's point of view.   This kind of paranoia is very common among first-time parents, so try to be understanding of her, she's just doing what she thinks is best for your child. Hopefully once she sees the actual research, she'll understand that her actions are counter-productive, and change her behaviors.

You both might enjoy these "first child, second child" commercials --they show how universal this is:
http://youtube.com/watch?v=ZMhHzucl9lI
 http://youtube.com/watch?v=UyhJazT3kqo